# Use printf to print ascii characters but printf will not print anything 100+ in Octal

Tags: linux, printf

I want to scroll through a list of octal numbers and print out their ASCII equivalents.  I can do this with

```
i=48
while [ $i -le 63 ]
do
   o=`echo "obase=8; $i" | bc`
   printf "\0$o\n"
   i=`expr $i + 1`
done
```

However if I change the range to 64 (Octal 100), to print @, the `printf "\0$o\n"` doesn't recognize the 3-digit Octal code.

What syntax should I be using with printf to be able to print ascii codes for 3-digit Octal numbers?

Comment: OK I've sorted it. The following shell copes with 3-digit octals. I realised I didn't need to specify the number in the printf command as being Octal. Also, note the "double back-slashes".

i=48
while [ $i -le 127 ]
do
   o=`echo "obase=8; $i" | bc`
   printf "\\$o\n"
   i=`expr $i + 1`
done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the `sh(1)` manpage, printf does not require a leading 0 when escaping octal codes. It's simply `printf '\100'`